# Уведомление через Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Как сделать уведомление в Windows на PowerShell, которое будет выводить кнопку, при нажатии которой меня будет перенаправлять на сайт? Я знаю, что есть множество различных API на C#, но меня интересует, можно ли это сделать на чистом PS?

Comment: Ну если "по-тупому - в лоб", то достаточно отправить сообщение, а затем вызвать открытие URL:`(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup("Visit web-site"); Invoke-Expression “cmd.exe /C start http://ya.ru”`